GitHub Actions Pipeline Fails During Azure Web App Deployment with ZIP Deploy
When I am using:
yaml

name: Zip artifact for deployment
run: zip -r release.zip ./* -x "logs/" ".env" "node_modules/"

and in the Azure Web App, I have set the environment variable SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT to true, I encountered the following error in the GitHub Actions pipeline during the deployment stage:
Run azure/webapps-deploy@v2
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
Fetching changes.
Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/a004467d-fb80-4497-b589-d18842459ba6.zip (7.96 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Deployment Failed, Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer to the logs for more details.
how to solve this error

The issue is with webapps-deploy version,  I am able deploy using azure/webapps-deploy@v3.

I tried sample code and deployed to Azure Web App through GitHub pipelines by adding @Run azure/webapps-deploy@v2 and  -   name: Zip artifact for deployment run: zip -r release.zip ./* -x "logs/_" ".env" "node_modules/_" to yml file as you have mentioned in your Question.
Then I got the same error, in order to avoid the error, I have changed @Run azure/webapps-deploy@v2  to @Run azure/webapps-deploy@v3 in GitHub Workflow file.
Below is my complete Workflow file.
GitHub Workflow File:
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - kareactapp24
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'
      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip -r release.zip ./* -x "logs/" ".env" "node_modules/"
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'kareactapp24'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_2CE09B03382F4CEE9BF83130962DD932 }}

After changing v2 to v3, it is successfully deployed.

Azure Web App Output:


@Sachin Bhatt Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
